# Parsing string containing Unicode character names

Tags: python, unicode

I have a string

```
>>> s
u'M\\N{AMPERSAND}M\\N{APOSTROPHE}s'
>>> print s
M\N{AMPERSAND}M\N{APOSTROPHE}s
```

How do I turn it into `M&M's`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`unicode_escape` encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

In Python 2.x:

```
>>> u'M\\N{AMPERSAND}M\\N{APOSTROPHE}s'.decode('unicode-escape')
u"M&M's"
```

In Python 3.x:

```
>>> u'M\\N{AMPERSAND}M\\N{APOSTROPHE}s'.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
"M&M's"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your `print` command I assume you are working in Python 2.
You can use `decode()` with an input which is the encoding you are using i.e. in this case `'unicode-escape'`

```
>>> s
u'M\\N{AMPERSAND}M\\N{APOSTROPHE}s'
>>>s.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> print s
"M&M's"
```